# Javascript: Best way to access/bind parent context/this inside nested scope

Tags: javascript

**Sample Code:**

```js
render: function() {
  this.getAsyncData(function() {
    this.specialFunction = (function(){
      //make nested calls again    
    }.bind(this));

    this.specialFunction();
  }.bind(this));
}
```

### Here are some know ways-

1. Use of `bind()` method
2. Use `var self = this;` and then use self inside

Please list all other possible ways to access parent context.

Comment: It all depends on what your needs are. `bind` handles more use-cases than `self` but `self` *generally* uses less memory. There is no "best" way.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can use fat arrows if you want to keep the same context.

And it's equal to ES6 code:

```
function Person() {
  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.age++; // |this| properly refers to the person object
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();
```

And it's equal to ES5 code:

```
function Person() {
  var _this = this;

  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(function () {
    _this.age++; // |this| properly refers to the person object
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();
```

You can read more about arrow functions here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

In Angular you can use `vm` for better handle scopes and avoid problems with nested scopes. It available since Angular add `controller as` syntax.

By using this feature, you can reach any scope you want without using $scope.$parent. It also provides you better readability and makes code easier to understand.

```
<div ng-controller="ShopController as shop">
  <p>{{ shop.name }}</p>
  <div ng-controller="CustomerController as customer">
    <p>{{ shop.address }}</p>
    <p>{{ customer.address }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read more here https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

Comment: This in no way addresses this question.

Comment: I added a sentence about fat arrows in ES6 but question is very general so I thought that it will be good to wrote about scopes in Angular.

Comment: It still doesn't address the question. Specifically, it's asking about the best way to access a parent scope in the general case. You're right about arrow functions but the bulk of your answer is talking about how to use the parent scope in Angular, which is not what this question is about.

Comment: I added more information and code examples for ES6 arrow functions.